# MS Access - Upsert Query Inserting All Data (Including Duplicate)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Probably a simple one for you however I'm clearly missing something (Lack of sleep and coffee thus far) Basically I have a mass import process based on multiple files to import event data into our database. Thing is the same data could appear in multiple spreadsheets so I import them all into a staging table and was attempting to use an upsert to insert new/update duplicates.

However... It basically just inserts all the data even if it is a "duplicate"

**How the data works:**

The table the excel sheets are being inserted into are for event attendees. In order to determine whether an 'Attendee' is unique or not we check 3 criteria,

***ContactID*** = Do they exist in the master data (This is FK - if they don't exist in contacts table they cannot be added as attendee)

***EventID*** = What event are they attending

***TypeID*** = What attendee type are they (Sponsor, Delegate, Speaker, etc...)

I have another upsert query for another import process however that only checks 1 field and works fine, however as this is checking 3 and for some reason is not working as intended.

***The following data is just a sample and the fields 'EventID', 'ContactID' and 'TypeID' are all Foreign Keys***

**Sample Data Before Upsert:**

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
| StagingID | EventID | ContactID | TypeID | IsDupe? |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
|         1 |       1 |         1 |      1 | No      |
|         2 |       1 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|         3 |       1 |         3 |      2 | No      |
|         4 |       1 |         2 |      1 | Yes     |
|         5 |       2 |         1 |      3 | No      |
|         6 |       2 |         2 |      2 | No      |
|         7 |       2 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|         8 |       2 |         3 |      1 | No      |
|         9 |       3 |         1 |      1 | No      |
|        10 |       3 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|        11 |       3 |         3 |      2 | No      |
|        12 |       3 |         3 |      3 | No      |
|        13 |       3 |         4 |      1 | No      |
|        14 |       3 |         2 |      1 | Yes     |
|        15 |       2 |         3 |      1 | Yes     |
+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

**Expected Results:** *(Actual results is just all the data in the table above)*

```
+------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
| AttendeeID | EventID | ContactID | TypeID | IsDupe? |
+------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
|          1 |       1 |         1 |      1 | No      |
|          2 |       1 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|          3 |       1 |         3 |      2 | No      |
|          4 |       2 |         1 |      3 | No      |
|          5 |       2 |         2 |      2 | No      |
|          6 |       2 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|          7 |       2 |         3 |      1 | No      |
|          8 |       3 |         1 |      1 | No      |
|          9 |       3 |         2 |      1 | No      |
|         10 |       3 |         3 |      2 | No      |
|         11 |       3 |         3 |      3 | No      |
|         12 |       3 |         4 |      1 | No      |
+------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

Basically anyone in the first table with 'yes' is a 'duplicate' as they are the same person going to the same event with the same attendance type.
*Note: The 'Duplicate' in the table is not a field, just a key for the purpose of this question*

```
UPDATE Out_Data LEFT JOIN In_Data ON (Out_Data.TypeID = In_Data.TypeID) AND (Out_Data.ContactID = In_Data.ContactID) AND (Out_Data.EventID = In_Data.EventID) SET In_Data.EventID = [Out_Data]![EventID], In_Data.ContactID = [Out_Data]![ContactID], In_Data.TypeID = [Out_Data]![TypeID], In_Data.Entry = [Out_Data]![Entry];
```

**Also:** Here is an Upsert Query I made that does actually do as intended:

```
UPDATE tbl_Contacts RIGHT JOIN tbl_STG_Suppression ON tbl_Contacts.Email = tbl_STG_Suppression.Email SET tbl_Contacts.Suppress = -1, tbl_Contacts.Email = [tbl_STG_Suppression]![Email];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the duplicates by checking the ID is the first ID to have the specified values you're checking for duplicates

```
UPDATE Out_Data 
LEFT JOIN In_Data ON (Out_Data.TypeID = In_Data.TypeID) AND (Out_Data.ContactID = In_Data.ContactID) AND (Out_Data.EventID = In_Data.EventID) 
SET In_Data.EventID = [Out_Data]![EventID], In_Data.ContactID = [Out_Data]![ContactID], In_Data.TypeID = [Out_Data]![TypeID], In_Data.Entry = [Out_Data]![Entry]
WHERE Out_Data.AttendeeID = 
(SELECT Min(s.AttendeeID)
FROM Out_Data s
WHERE s.EventID = Out_Data.EventID AND s.ContactId = Out_data.ContactID AND Out_Data.TypeID = s.TypeID)
```

Note that performance might be improved by first removing duplicates and then upserting the data. If you do that, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to deduplicate data, in upsert queries that's not available.

Comment: The -1 under entry is just a sample table so that people can Identify the non-unique records in said sample table. The actual tables I'm using and the data following the 3 criteria (EventID, ContactID, TypeID) is completely different.

If you imagine it without the -1 the upsert should basically look at the first 3 and if there is no matches to the existing data insert that recordset - if there is a match, update that recordset

Comment: Well, then add your actual data as sample data, including both tables, since as it currently looks you just want to insert, not upsert

Comment: "Well, then add your actual data as sample data" - That would breach quite a few of the GDPR regulations

Comment: Then add representative data. My answer is valid for the data you've displayed

Comment: I have amended the sample tables as I can understand the confusion

Comment: Why is row 4 a dupe, and row 2 isn't one, in an unordered data set? There is no way to distinguish between them without a separate ID column...

Comment: All my tables do have a unique ID - I just didn't include in the sample data as I felt it was redundant data. The primary key for this data/table would be 'AttendeeID'

Edited Question again... I'm so bad at this